# hide button for specific product(s)

Tags: hook-woocommerce

All items on my woocommerce shop have this button:

```
<a class="button e-custom-product " onclick="return loadProductDesign(this);" data-product_id="108" href="https://www.bedrukt.nl/ontwerp/?product_id=1974">Bedrukken</a>
```

On two specific items (for now) I would like to hide this button.
The button plugin does not include this function.

Let's say on item: https://domeinnam.nl/ontwerpen/hoodie-unisex/ I would like the above button to be hidden.

Like to do it without plugins, so maybe this can be done with the functions.php?
Would anyone care to help me get started with the code, for something like:

"If item='hoodie-unisex' then hide button.

I tried to find some code for functions.php to get this done, but cannot find it and am not able to write it myself from scratch.